# how to run a class after other java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I need to execute a test that is in a class after other test that is in another class.
I am using TestNG-Java-Selenium, I tried to use  dependsOnGroups , but I was not able to make it work.
These are my two classes:
The first one is to block a user and verify that the login is disabled.

@BeforeClass

```
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
     this.setUpMaven();
 }



 @AfterClass // call function to close browser 

    public void teardown(){
     this.quitBrowser();
    }





@Test
public void loginAsInactive() throws Exception{

    personas = new PersonasPage(driver);

    login = new LoginPage(driver);


    Reporter.log(" Probar que un usuario inactivo no se puede loguear");

 // Go to the configuration
    this.goToConfiguration();
    this.goToMenu();

       // Go to Manage people
         personas.goToPersonas();
        WebElement someElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(inputSearch)));
            this.sendValue(inputSearch, "Inactive");


         this.click(".tables tbody tr td:nth-child(7) a");


         this.click(".basicdata label:nth-child(3) input ");
        ;
         this.click(".container .addpeople .primary");

        this.goToMenuUsuario();
          this.logout();

         login.loginToGo("marina.touceda+058@gointegro.com", "Auto1234");
         Thread.sleep(2000);
                     Reporter.log(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.reject")).getText());
```

The other one has the same setup, but has to activate the user and verify the login.
Can someone give some guidelines?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at TestSuites? You can group test cases in these and execute them in order.

Answer (score 1):

Its become very easy if you can run as testng suite. If you don't know how to create testng.xml then follow below steps

```
  Right click on src folder (as per eclipse)
  Go to TestNG and select Convert to TestNG
  testng.xml preview is displayed with all TestNG classes which contains @Test methods
  Click on Finish
```

After finish, open that testng.xml file, keep required classes if more is there, here required two in required order, and also use

```
preserve-order="true"
```

to run classes in provided order.
It  looks like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
  <test name="Test1">
   <classes>
    <class name="com.test.Test1"/>
    <class name="com.test.Test2"/>
  </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

Just run above xml file.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Yes, I have already set to run these classes with TestNG.Finally I was able to do it with the {depends on "test"}.Thanks for your responses..!